# Inheriting features from a JavaScript class

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework

I am trying to make a simple JavaScript game. In the game, all game objects should be able to be dragged and dropped. For now, this code does the trick:

```
function create() {
  game.stage.backgroundColor = 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5)'
  combinator = game.add.sprite(10, 15, 'Combinator')
  comparer = game.add.sprite(100, 15, 'Comparer')
  button = game.add.sprite(50, 15, 'Button')  

  button.inputEnabled = true;
  button.input.enableDrag(true);
  combinator.inputEnabled = true;
  combinator.input.enableDrag(true);
  comparer.inputEnabled = true;
  comparer.input.enableDrag(true);  

}
```

But I am trying to make a class for all gameObjects where inputEnabled= true and input.enableDrag(true), so that I only need to define this once. Something like this I presume:

```
class gameObject {
  constructor () {
    this.inputEnabled = true;
    this.input.enableDrag(true);
  }
}
```

But I cant get my head around how this would then be used in the create function. Do I need to make game.add.sprite(x,y,'name') a part of the class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a factory class that creates the sprites for you.

```
class SpriteFactory {
    constructor(game) {
        this.game = game
    }

    getDraggableSprite(...spriteParameters) {
        const sprite = this.game.add.sprite(...spriteParameters)
        sprite.inputEnabled = true
        sprite.input.enableDrag(true)
        return sprite
    }
}

function create() {
  game.stage.backgroundColor = 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5)'

  const spriteFactory = new SpriteFactory(game)

  combinator = spriteFactory.getDraggableSprite(10, 15, 'Combinator')
  comparer = spriteFactory.getDraggableSprite(100, 15, 'Comparer')
  button = spriteFactory.getDraggableSprite(50, 15, 'Button')  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You want your class to inherit from the `Phaser.Sprite` class:

```
class gameObject extends Phaser.Sprite {
  constructor (game, x, y, key) {
    super(game, x, y, key);
    this.inputEnabled = true;
    this.input.enableDrag(true);
  }
}
```

Then your create function will look something like this:

```
function create() {
  game.stage.backgroundColor = 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5)'
  combinator = game.add.existing(new gameObject(game, 10, 15, 'Combinator'))
  comparer = game.add.existing(new gameObject(game, 100, 15, 'Comparer'))
  button = game.add.existing(new gameObject(game, 50, 15, 'Button')) 
}
```